# Explanation of graph degeneracy

Tags: graph-theory

I am having problems understanding the definition of graph $k$-degeneracy. The problem has been asked multiple times in this board, but I cant find a explanation that clarifies the problem for me.

So, let me walk you through my problem with understanding.

First, we have the definition of $k$-degeneracy:

> A graph $G$ is said to be $k$-degenerate if every subgraph of $G$ has a vertex of degree at most $k$.
>   (from [Definition of degeneracy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575265/definition-of-degeneracy))

and similar:

> A $k$-degenerate graph is an undirected graph in which every induced subgraph has minimum degree at most $k$. The degeneracy of a graph is the smallest $k$ for which it is $k$-degenerate.
>   (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms#degeneracy)

A big problem I have here is the part with "every subgraph". Lets just quickly check the definition of "subgraph":

> A subgraph of a graph $G$ is another graph formed from a subset of the vertices and edges of $G$. The vertex subset must include all endpoints of the edge subset, but may also include additional vertices [...].
>   (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms#subgraph)

or, similar:

> A subgraph of a graph $G=(V,E)$ is a graph $G'=(V',E')$ such that $E'$ is a subset of $E$, $G'$ is a subset of  and all the vertices connected by the edges in $E'$ are in the subset $G'$.
>   (from [Definition of a subgraph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2707170/definition-of-a-subgraph))

So, if $k$-degeneracy is the number $k$ of a graph, from which **EVERY** (induced) subgraph has at most the degree $k$, what about the (**ALWAYS** existing) minimal subgraph of ZERO vertices and ZERO edges?

Formally: $G_{sub} := (V_{sub}, E_{sub})$, with $V_{sub} = \emptyset$ and $E_{sub} = \emptyset$

$\Delta(G_{sub})$ of this subgraph is zero. Same goes if the subgraph has only ONE vertex. As it always exists, it is ONE OF the (induced) subgraphs of G. As $\Delta(G_{sub})$ is zero, $\delta(v)$ is zero for any $v \in V_{sub}$, hence the degeneracy is also always zero. For all graphs.

Obviously, I am missing a crucial part of the definition here. Anyone here able to point this out to me?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You've identified *one* possible subgraph with a vertex of degree at most $0$, but this doesn't imply that *every* subgraph has degree at most $0$, as would be required for $0$-degeneracy. (For example, one subgraph to consider is $G$ itself, so the degeneracy is always at least $\delta(G)$.)

Comment: Well, I am not a native speaker, but I read "at most k" as "k or less, but never more". So, as I understand it, I need to show that EVERY subgraph of G has (at least) one vertex with degree k !?

Comment: Well, that would mean that I just have to find **A** subgraph of G with the highest possible $k$ !??? Per default, that would be the degree of the vertex with the highest degree. Always. In every graph. What is the use of degeneracy then?

Comment: You might want to consult this question and its answers, which seem similar to your followup question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575265/definition-of-degeneracy?rq=1

In short, the degeneracy isn't always equal to the maximum degree: you can't just take a vertex of max degree as your subgraph and keep its degree the same, because you'd need to pull in its neighbors. For example, the star $K_{1, n-1}$ is $1$-degenerate: every subgraph either contains a leaf vertex (of degree $1$) or, if it the center vertex but no leaves, then the center vertex has degree $0$ in that subgraph.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but then again here's my problem AGAIN: Is there any restriction in how to choose the subgraph? As far as I understand, there is none! So if I select any subgraph with **NO** edges from the star $K_1$ (or ANY graph), I have a subgraph with degree zero at most.

Comment: You can take any subgraph except for the "subgraph" with no vertices (many authors wouldn't even consider the "graph with no vertices" to be a graph). But to be $k$-degenerate, you need *EVERY* subgraph to have a vertex of degree at most $k$, so a subgraph with no edges doesn't tell you anything interesting about the degeneracy of the original graph.

Comment: OK, understood. Thanks. Still, if every subgraph of $G$ has to have a vertex with degree of at most $k$, EVERY graph is $k$-degenerate for $k = max \{\delta(v) | v \in G\}$, right? I mean, the maximum degree in ANY subgraph would still be $k$. Cant be higher - ever. So then - whats the "use" or "meaning" of degeneracy?

Comment: Sure, any graph $G$ is $\Delta(G)$-degenerate, but it might also be $k$-degenerate for $k < \Delta(G)$. (For example, $K_{1,n-1}$ is $1$-degenerate but has max degree $n-1$.) Sometimes this is useful -- for example, if you're doing graph coloring, you can always color a graph with $\Delta(G)+1$ colors, but in fact if $G$ is $k$-degenerate, you can color it with $k+1$ colors, so being able to take $k < \Delta(G)$ saves us some colors here.

Comment: thanks a lot!!!